# Rails undefined method `persisted?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, api, mongoid

I working using rails 
my project make API using mongodb

and I got this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `persisted?'for ActionController::Parameters:0x000055f487fc4ac8

This error is in my controller on create method:

```
  def create
    if @merchant.order.push(get_params)
     render json: {:response => true, :status => "ok"}
    else
     render json: {:response => false, :status => "ok"}
    end
  end

  def get_params
  params.required(:order).permit!
  end
```

This is my model:

```
class Order
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :items
 field :grand_total, type: Integer

 belongs_to :merchant
end
```

I appreciate all kind of support, thank you.

Comment: can I see `get_params` method?

Comment: @HardikUpadhyayi already add the get params sory for that

Comment: huntz please follow @Ana María Martínez Gómez answer, if you still face any issue than let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` accept an instance of `Order` and I assume you are passing something like `ActionController::Parameters`. Also, `push` always returns an association. I think if this failed, it would be with an exception and then the `if` makes no sense. I suggest to use `create` instead. So (assuming get_params is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` or a `Hash` and that `order` is a `has_many` relationship):

```
if @merchant.order.create(get_params)
   render json: {:response => true, :status => "ok"}
  else
   render json: {:response => false, :status => "ok"}
  end
end
```

If it is a `hash_one` relationship, it should be something like:

```
params = get_params.merge(merchant: @merchant)
if @Order.create(params)
   render json: {:response => true, :status => "ok"}
  else
   render json: {:response => false, :status => "ok"}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `push` accepts a record (a model), not a hash of params:

```
label = Label.first
label.bands.push(Band.first)
```

[Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#dependent-behaviour)
Mongoid checks if the model is persisted, that's why `#persisted?` is called on `ActionController::Parameters` that you pass there.

Try sth like

```
@merchant.order.push(Order.new(get_params))
```

if `order` is has_many relationship or

```
@merchant.order = Order.new(get_params)
```

if `order` is has_one relationship.